# Is there a 'BroadcastReciver' in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to listen all SMS receive in flutter to analyze some of them.
I Implement it in Java with BroadcastReceiver class and some method to pass data into Flutter.

My question is 'Is it possible to use BroadcastReceiver in Flutter not using native?'

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. All platform specific services and methods to be implemented using a `MethodChannel` or `EventChannel`. In your case, you can handle the native events with `BroadcastReceiver` and forward it to flutter using an `EventChannel`.

For more details about platform specific code check the docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: *"All platform specific services and methods to be implemented using a MethodChannel or EventChannel"* - in addition to `MethodChannel` and `EventChannel` you can also use `BasicMessageChannel`

Comment: Thanks. But i have another question. How to active a Flutter activity when sth received? I mean when a SMS received app navigate to a specific page.

Comment: If you are looking for navigating in a flutter applications, you can pass events with arguments, like details of sms and route to navigate etc via the appropriate channel, then handle it on flutter, check the arguments and navigate to appropriate route using `Navigator`. If you are looking for deep-links, url schemes, check out [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained)

You need to add this to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  sms: ^0.2.0
```

To receive SMS

```
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() {
  SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
  receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body));
}
```

[More in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/geordyvcErasmus/flutter_sms)

Comment: can i get the phone number?

Comment: @Saeiddjawadi `SmsMessage` has a get property called `sender`, not sure if it returns the number, try it